# IE8 CSS floated div issue(s)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have inherited a site that has significant issues when displayed in IE8. Looks like a lot of them are div related, but I could use some help in fixing the problem.

The issue I am working on right now is that the divs for the phone numbers and flags are being displayed on two lines, instead of one. This ends up pushing down the content of the nav bar.

URL: fertileweb.com/demosite (slightly dated copy, latest is hosted locally)

IE8 view: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjXwP.jpg

IE10/firefox/chrome view: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxDIm.jpg

HTML

```
<div class="addressBox">
<span>Call for a private consultation</span>
<ul>
<li>
<img src="http://localhost/orh/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/USA.png">
(425) 646-4700
</li>
<li>
<img src="http://localhost/orh/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/canada.png">
(800) 394-2402
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.addressBox {
float: right;
padding-top: 35px;}

.addressBox span {
color: #231F20;
display: block;
font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 26px;
text-align: right;}

.addressBox ul {
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;}

.addressBox li {
color: #231F20;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 26px;
padding-left: 17px;}

.addressBox li img {
float: left;
margin: 3px 7px 0 0;}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your CSS styles

```
.addresBox ul, .addresBox ul li {
  white-space:nowrap;   
}
```

The problem seems to be about browsers size instead of browsers version.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In this case I was able to solve the overflow by setting the width of the li elements to 133px. 

White-space:nowrap; also put the content onto one line, but there was a spacing issue between the <img> and text elements so I just went with the simple fix of setting the width. What did you mean about the browser size? Why would IE8 have a different sized browser than say IE9?

Answer (score 0):

If a wordwrap doesn't make it, I would suggest using the `display: table;` option, as such:

```
.addressBox { display: table; width: 500px; }
.addressBox li { display: table-cell; }
```

That usually solves floating errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have never heard of using display:table before.  Perhaps it will help me solve some of the other issues :)

Comment: The best thing about `display: table` is the fact you can have perfectly aligned div's at the same height, allowing for a continuous background throughout the flexible height.

Answer (score 0):

working full code with demo here

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/r63bg/)

### html code:

```
<div class="addressBox"> 
    <span>Call for a private consultation</span>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://images.apple.com/global/elements/flags/22x22/usa.png"> (425) 646-4700</li>
        <li><img src="http://images.apple.com/ca/global/elements/flags/22x22/canada.png"> (800) 394-2402</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### css code:

```
.addressBox {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

.addressBox span {
    color: #231F20;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: right;
}

.addressBox ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.addressBox li {
    color: #231F20;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0 0 0 17px;
    margin:0;
}

.addressBox li img {
    float: left;
    margin: 3px 7px 0 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Good work. I like the jsFiddle tool,  I think I will be able to get some good use out of that. I think this code has the same problem as mine in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why, but adding the code below fixed the problem by making sure the element didn't get too small for the content - which would cause the text to wrap.I made sure to add it to a conditional style so it wouldn't have any other adverse effects.

```
.addressbox li {
width:133px;
}
```